# How to integrate Admob in xdk

Tags: cordova, admob, intel-xdk, intel-xdk-contacts

I have used the links below and I always receive this error **admob plugin not ready** on device.

[https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob]
[https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/adding-google-play-services-to-your-cordova-application]

What should I do? Please, help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here is a simple `AdMob` example that works when built with Intel XDK, try this:
https://github.com/krisrak/html5-cordova-plugin-admob

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
I have tried it and it has worked with your Keys. But if I add my Keys(admob_ios_key and admob_ios_key_interstitial) all I can see is a black screen in the place where a banner should be shown. What have I forgotten? Maybe something in google admob? Thank you for your answer in Advance.

Comment: can u set `isTesting: true` and try with your keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you waiting for `deviceready` to start the ads? (see this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26214464/4025963):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  document.removeEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  if (admob) {
     // YOUR ADMOB KEY HERE
    admob.createBannerView({publisherId: 'ca-app-pub-xxx/xxx'});
    admob.requestInterstitialAd({interstitialAdId: 'ca-app-pub-xxx/xxx', autoShowInterstitial: true});
  }
}
```

I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova and it works for me and it also has an example of integration with intel XDK that I've tested in an iPhone.

Comment: It works now.
My admob wasn't correct. I have corrected it and it is working now. Thank you all.